# How can I fit this Naive-Bayes model?. ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, machine-learning, naivebayes

I am trying to fit a NB model in Python and I am always getting the same error, even though dimensions of features and labels are correct for the fitting.

```py
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

model = GaussianNB()

model.fit(features,labels)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-bce1b5fdfb0c> in <module>
      5 model = GaussianNB()
      6 
----> 7 model.fit(features,labels)
      8 
      9 #predicted = model.predict([[0.086469175340272,0.049800796812749,0.017614091273018002,0.013090495162208001,1]])

c:\users\marta\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    188         self : object
    189         """
--> 190         X, y = check_X_y(X, y)
    191         return self._partial_fit(X, y, np.unique(y), _refit=True,
    192                                  sample_weight=sample_weight)

c:\users\marta\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    754                     ensure_min_features=ensure_min_features,
    755                     warn_on_dtype=warn_on_dtype,
--> 756                     estimator=estimator)
    757     if multi_output:
    758         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,

c:\users\marta\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    525             try:
    526                 warnings.simplefilter('error', ComplexWarning)
--> 527                 array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
    528             except ComplexWarning:
    529                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

c:\users\marta\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    536 
    537     """
--> 538     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    539 
    540 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

My features and labels are like:

```py
features.shape = (4430, 5)
len(features[n][m]) = 306
labels.shape = (4430,)
len(labels[i]) = 306
```

And features and labels are of the form:

```
features = array([[list([1, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6]),list([1, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6]),
list([1, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6]),list([1, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6]),list([1, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6])],
[list([0, 218, 234, 195, 201, 229]),list([0, 218, 234, 195, 201, 229]),
list([0, 218, 234, 195, 201, 229]),list([0, 218, 234, 195, 201, 229]),
list([0, 218, 234, 195, 201, 229])], dtype=object)

labels = array([list([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),list([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

I have also tried fitting it to other models and doesn't work also, and have reviewed other posts here and all talk about the dimension of the matrices, but .shape gives good dimensions for both to work (as far as I am concerned).

What can I do to fit this model?

Comment: it looks like your labels has size `(4430,5)` but probably it shoud be `(4430,1)` . You have 2-dimensional array but it should be 1-dimensional list.

Comment: @furas could you please elaborate a little bit more about this? The dimension of my features is 5, as I have 5 variables in the dataset that I will try to predict when the model is fitted (OCR project, data of positions)

Comment: In the sample data you provided `labels = np.array([list([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),list([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])])` then `labels.shape` is `(2,6)`. The dependent variable should be one dimensional

Comment: I'm not expert but in every cell you have list with 6 values but it should be single number. It works for me if I use `model.fit(features[0], labels[0][:5])`